# Use Specific Case Field to Create Chatter Feed Item

Tags: case, chatter, feeditem

Currently I've noticed when a Chatter feed item gets created for a Case record, the Auto Number field is what the Post initially gets created with.

[image]

We've got a separate Case Name field that is more meaningful to the user than the auto generated number.

Is there a way to create the Post with a specific field as the "title" rather than the auto number field?

Comment: Does https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366295/populate-case-subject-in-chatter-feed-post help?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Feed Tracking settings for the case object and uncheck the Casenumber and check the Case title (or field you want to see).

[image]